# How to integrate GitHub private repository to my Gerrit server

Tags: github, repository, integration, gerrit, private-repository

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently in the process of integrating Gerrit with GitHub, following the guide provided here: [link to the guide](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/github).

Upon completion of the setup process, I was able to view and connect to public repositories in my Gerrit server. However, I'm facing an issue where my private repositories on GitHub do not appear on the list.

Furthermore, while there's a link provided to "Login with a different GitHub Scope", clicking on it does not show any list or options in the "Login Scope Selection" screen.

Currently, I am using the free plan of GitHub. I'm wondering if this issue is related to my plan and whether private repository integration is only available with paid GitHub plans.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you for your help in advance!

Best,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCZVu.png)

I need private repository in the list , so I can connect the repository with my gerrit server